# Métodos estáticos

Tags: java, static

¿Una clase  siempre debe ser diseñada para que "siempre" sea instanciada o pueden existir clases en las cuales nunca se creen objetos pero si se utilicen metodos estáticos?
¿Si esto es posible,  sería una buena práctica?

Answer (score 1):

Con respecto a tu consulta de si una clase debe ser diseñada para que "siempre" sea instanciada, existe un patrón de diseño llamado Singleton, el cuál se utiliza para que una clase no pueda ser instanciada "siempre", la responsabilidad de instanciar o no recae en su método estático, el cual es diseñado para evaluar si esa clase existe o no, si no existe aún, pues la instancia y la retorna, y si ya existe, no la instancia y retorna el valor que ya existía, es muy útil por ejemplo cuando se trabaja con conexiones al servidor, ya que si la conexión se encuentra abierta, es preferible que no se abra otra y se trabaje con la conexión ya existente.

Ahora con respecto a tener una clase para utilizar únicamente sus métodos static sin tener que instanciarla nunca, claro que se puede ya que es una funcionalidad de Java, más que buenas prácticas, será el tipo de problema que quieras resolver en donde este escenario sería la mejor solución, recuerda que en programación no hay un solo camino.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible hacer una clase con todos los métodos estáticos, el propio lenguaje java tiene este tipo de clases donde agrupa funcionalidades que se pueden usar en otras clases, ver la clase [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html)

En cuanto a "buenas prácticas" depende si estas trabajando con otros programadores o en una empresa deberías consultar o acordar con ellos como trabajar.

Caso contrario depende del programador (siempre que todos los métodos sean estáticos y que no tenga un constructor explícito).